# Nodejs run configuration is missing in intellij 2018.1

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea

I upgraded Intellj IDEA from 2017.3 to 2018.1. Now, when I opened a nodejs project in IDEA, the run configuration is shown as broken. Also, the run configuration list doesn't have Nodejs in it, so I cannot create a new Nodejs run configuration either.

[image]

What has happened to Nodejs run configuration? Is there any way to get it back?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The auto update prompt for the plugins has not worked for some reason. I manually checked for an update for the Nodejs plugin and an update was there. When plugin is updated, the run configuration started to work.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. 
my intellij was set with node configuration and one day the configuration was marked with an X and I couldn't recover it nor create a new one.
upgrading the NodeJS version to (at least) v191.6183.20 and it solved the issue.
ctrl + alt + s -->  plugins --> NodeJS  click update.